# iMessage appears to be blocked, but FaceTime rings

Tags: ipad, facetime

Something confusing happened on my iPad today. One of my contacts' number has been red instead of blue in iMessage for sometime now. I cannot send them a text through iMessage. The send button isn't even active with their number. I know that typically means I am blocked or their number is no longer associated with their Apple ID.

However, today I decided to try FaceTime on that number. It rang more than 6 times. There was no answer. But why would it ring if the number doesn't work with iMessage?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because the person your are messaging turned off their Apple ID from iMessage. You’re iPad is trying to send a text message but because you’re not on an iPhone it can’t.

FaceTime was ringing because the person didn’t turn off FaceTime but only iMessage.